# How do I project a rotation-matrix to the x/z-axis in order to create a radar?

Tags: windows-phone-7, matrix, xna

I'm creating a showcase-game that uses the sensors of the phone to look around in the 3d-game world. I would like to create a radar in xna that displays the opponents nearby.
I use the rotation-matrix from the MotionReader. How can I calculate this with the RotationMatrix? I know how it works when I use the compass (heading) to create a y-rotation-matrix:

```
Matrix rotation = Matrix.CreateRotationY(MathHelper.ToRadians((float)trueHeading));
EffectRadar.View = rotation * Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0, 1.1f, 0), new Vector3(0, -1, 0), new Vector3(0, 0, -1));
```

Since I'm using the motion-reader I get much better values if a device has a gyroscope and I don't want to write my own filter for the compass-heading.

I tried this, but it doesnt work when I pitch the phone:

```
Matrix rotation = Matrix.CreateRotationX(MathHelper.PiOver2) * motion.CurrentValue.Attitude.RotationMatrix;
EffectRadar.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(0, 1.1f, 0), new Vector3(0, -1, 0), new Vector3(0, 0, -1));
EffectRadar.Projection = Matrix.CreateOrthographic(FarClippingDistance / 2.0f, FarClippingDistance / 2.0f, 1.0f, 10.0f);
foreach (Opponent item in opponentList){
    Vector3 vecProj = RadarViewport.Project(new Vector3(item.Position.X, 0.0f, item.Position.Z),
        EffectRadar.Projection,
        rotation,
        Matrix.Identity
    );

    EffectRadar.World = Matrix.CreateTranslation(vecProj.X, 0.0f, vecProj.Z);
    foreach (EffectPass pass in EffectRadar.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
    {
        pass.Apply();
        GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionColor>(PrimitiveType.TriangleStrip, VerticesColorRed, 0, 2);
    }
}
```

Hope you can help me.

Comment: I don't understand. You mean the phone's display is a "window" into the 3D world? This would mean that the compass heading = yaw and the gyroscope gives you pitch and roll for a first person camera, correct?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I mean

Answer (score 0):

Any articles on how to create a first-person camera will be of help to you, for example [Riemers XNA tutorial > Mouse camera](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series4/Mouse_camera.php). This has what you need, a leftRightRot and an upDownRot which correspond to yaw and pitch. if you need roll you'd need to re-orient your up-vector but this should be trivial once you have the rest going.

Comment: Thank's for your answer. In fact I implemented the first-person view already. I wanted to create a radar where I display the opponents in the vicinity as little dots. I wanted to know if and how I can use the rotation-matrix instead of the compass-heading in order to rotate them depending on the direction I'm looking at.

Comment: If the opponents are positioned in 3D space there's no need to rotate them. They will automatically move in relation to the camera, no?

Comment: Yes, from the first-person view. But I want to create a 2D-radar in the top-left corner.